# How to repeat process of random position and image with this code

Tags: android, random

What I want to do is that each time I tap the TextView, the stars will get their random position which was set in my layout.

It works after the first click, but some stars are missing from the next click on the textview.

```
List<Integer> imageViews = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> images = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void clearimg()
    {
        str1.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        str2.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        str3.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        str4.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        str5.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        str6.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        str7.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        str8.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        str9.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        str10.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    }

public void viewadd()
{
    imageViews.add(R.id.star1);
    imageViews.add(R.id.star2);
    imageViews.add(R.id.star3);
    imageViews.add(R.id.star4);
    imageViews.add(R.id.star5);
    imageViews.add(R.id.star6);
    imageViews.add(R.id.star7);
    imageViews.add(R.id.star8);
    imageViews.add(R.id.star9);
    imageViews.add(R.id.star10);
}


public void imageadd()
{
    images.add(R.drawable.star1);
    images.add(R.drawable.star2);
    images.add(R.drawable.star3);
    images.add(R.drawable.star4);
    images.add(R.drawable.star5);
    images.add(R.drawable.star6);
    images.add(R.drawable.star7);
    images.add(R.drawable.star8);
    images.add(R.drawable.star9);
    images.add(R.drawable.star10);
}

View.OnClickListener tapHandler = new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               clearimg();
             imageadd();
                viewadd();


               Random rng = new Random(); 
                List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                  while(true)
                    {

                      Integer next = rng.nextInt(imageViews.size()) ;
                      if (!generated.contains(next))
                        {
                         generated.add(next);
                         ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(imageViews.get(next));
                         iv.setImageResource(images.get(next));
                         images.remove(next);
                         imageViews.remove(next);
                         break;
                        }
                    }



                }


          }
    };
```

Comment: after setting your image to your `ImageView` delete "i"th item from your list. no duplicate any more. ;)

Comment: Can you please explain it a little bit clearer and further? I somehow get your point .. and somehow not.

Comment: see my answer for further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 List<Integer> views = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 List<Integer> images = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 //populate your lists
```

you should remove used resources from your lists. here is an example.
in your while :

```
 Integer next = rng.nextInt(views.size()) ;
 if (!generated.contains(next))
 {
    generated.add(next);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(views.get(next));
    iv.setImageResource(images.get(next));
    images.remove(next);
    views.remove(next);
    break;
 }
```

Comment: I was about to throw the answer. Had a popup saying "1 new answer" and saw my solution ;) +1 for it.

Comment: Oh wait. I'll try again.